# How to keep track of timeouts in callbacks

Tags: javascript, timer

Say I have this bit of code and I want to know when all of the callbacks have been completed. How would I do that?

```
var cb1 = function() {


setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('cb1 fired');
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
};

var cb2 = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('cb2 fired');
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
};
var cb3 = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('cb3 fired');
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
};

function fireCBs(cbArray) {
}

fireCBs([cb1, cb2, cb3]);
```

Comment: Do you just want to know when the function have fired or are you trying to execute yet another function when all have fired?

Comment: I apologize, it is the latter I am looking for. I'd like to call another function after the rest have completed.

Comment: This is the exact problem that Promise.all() solves.  Unfortunately, Promises aren't standardized yet.

Answer (score 0):

First I would not duplicate code like you have. each function calls set timeout with random interval.  Because of this you can simplify your code.  Below is a basic simplification of your code that will allow you to modify how you call the setTimeout in one place.   In addition it standardizes the function calling for each of your CBs.  Finally, I added Timeout period as a property to TimeoutFunctions that would allow you customize the timeout periods.

```
var Utilities = {
  TimeoutFunctions: [
    {
      timeoutPeriod: null,
      fn: function() {
        console.log("cb1 fired");
      }
    },
    {
      timeoutPeriod: null,
      fn: function() {
        console.log("cb2 fired");
      }
    },
    {
      timeoutPeriod: null,
      fn: function() {
        console.log("cb3 fired");
      }
    }
  ],
  fireCBs: function() {
    Utilities.totalCBsFired = Utilities.TimeoutFunctions.length;
    for (var i=0; i < Utilities.TimeoutFunctions.length; i++) {
      setTimeout((function(fn){
        return function () {
          fn();
          Utilities.totalCBsFired --;
          if (Utilities.totalCBsFired == 0) {
            //Execute your extra code here
            console.log("all cbs fired");
          }
        };
      })(Utilities.TimeoutFunctions[i].fn),
      Utilities.TimeoutFunctions[i].timeoutPeriod || (Math.random() * 1000));
    }
  }
}

Utilities.fireCBs();
```

OK tested the code and its working.  Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/esqJ5/

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  but above is a potential solution with a working demo